# Does the restriction of the Thom class of a submanifold to the cohomology of the submanifold give the Chern class of the normal bundle?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold of (complex) dimension $d$, let $i\colon Y\hookrightarrow X$ be a regular complex submanifold of (complex) codimension $k$, let $\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$ be the normal bundle over $Y$, let $c_k(\mathcal{N})\in H^{2k}(Y,{\mathbb{R}})$ be the top Chern class of the normal bundle, and let $\eta_Y\in H^{2k}(X,{\mathbb{R}})$ denote the Thom class of $Y\subset X$.  Is it always the case that 
$$i^*(\eta_Y)=c_k(\mathcal{N})?$$

$\textbf{Edit:}$

According to pg. 9 of user's notes (or pg. 66 of Bott-Tu's book), what I called the Thom class of $Y\subset X$ should really be called the Poincar\'e dual of $Y\subset X$.  But we can identify this class with the Thom class of the normal bundle $\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$, which lives in $H^{2k}_{cv}(\mathcal{N}_{Y/X})$, (the compact vertical cohomology ring of $\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$), by first identifying $\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$ with a tubular neighborhood of $Y\subset X$, and then ''extending by zero'':  write this maps as $j_*\colon H(\mathcal{N}_{Y/X})\rightarrow H(X)$, where $j\colon \mathcal{N}_{Y/X}\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion of the normal bundle as a tubular neighborhood.  On the other hand, we could also pull this Thom class back to a cohomology class on $Y$ by the zero section:  $s^*\colon H(\mathcal{N}_{Y/X})\rightarrow H(Y)$.  Then according to user's comments below (or Proposition 12.4 on pg. 132 of Bott-Tu) the pullback of the Thom class by the zero section is always the Euler class of the bundle (which is the top Chern class).  So now my original question can be rephrased as follows:  is it always the case that
$$s^*\Phi=i^*j_*\Phi$$
where $\Phi\in H^{2k}(\mathcal{N}_{Y/X})$ is the Thom class of the normal bundle, and $i^*$ is the restriction map as above?

Comment: I think this is true (at least when everything is projective). The Chern class of the normal bundle (maybe the projectivized normal bundle, I don't remember now) is exactly the class of  $Y$ in the Chow ring under rational equivalence (I'm not sure of the equivalence maybe it's algebraic instead), so this should coincide with the Poincaré dual and hence the Thom class of the normal bundle (maybe the projectivization of the bundle).

Comment: See in page 12 http://w3.impa.br/~massaren/files/CCCAG.pdf. The top Chern class coincides with the Euler class. Therefore, since the Euler class is the pullback of the Thom class by a section, your claim will hold. So a more general statement holds. Given a complex vector bundle $E$ and a section $s: X \rightarrow E$, $s^{*} \Phi (E_{\mathbb{R}}) = c_{k} (E)$ where $\Phi $ is the Thom class.

Comment: @user40276 you don't want to make this an answer?

Comment: @peterag If I have time to write down the details of my claim, I may post this as an answer. But now I don't have time.

Comment: @user40276 Thanks for the link.  I don't quite see how your comment answers my question though...but perhaps I have misunderstood something.  In light of your notes/comments, I will edit my question.

Comment: Maybe you don't know the tubular neighborhood theorem. The point is that $i$ (with the codomain restricted to the tubular neighborhood) is exactly the zero section. So your rephrased question also holds.

Comment: @user40276 yes after I rephrased it my question seemed rather obvious...thanks for your comments!